# Get text of button with font style in android

Tags: android, view, textview, android-button

Anyone knows how to get the text of any component like textview, button, or edit text with it is current font style.
My issue is that I am getting a normal text with text view.getText() but I want to text with the custom font which I have applied with Typeface.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Share the code that you've tried.

Comment: I want to send text with custom font when i click from custom keyboard for that i have used below code.
 val spannableString = SpannableString(btnA!!.text)
                spannableString.setSpan(
                    TypefaceSpan(baseContext,"fonts/font1.ttf"),
                    btnA!!.text.toString().indexOf(btnA!!.text.toString()),
                    btnA!!.text.toString().indexOf(btnA!!.text.toString())+ btnA!!.text.length,
                    Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE
                )
 currentInputConnection.commitText(spannableString,1) but no luck

Comment: I have direct get text like this
currentInputConnection.commitText(btnA.text.toString(),1) but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Share your code and what you have done until now in your thread, if you get error include it to your post. Here guide for asking in SO [Guide Ask in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)